# How is the critical value calculated in rpact package?

Tags: sample-size, effect-size

A critical value (treatment effect scale) is output as 0.127 from R code:

```
require(rpact)
getPowerRates(groups=1, sided=1, alpha=0.025, thetaH0=0.075, pi1=0.2, maxNumberOfSubjects=100)
```

How is the critical value calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the upper bound of a normal-approximate confidence interval under $H_0$, i.e.

$$
\theta_0+z_{1-\alpha}\times \sqrt{\theta_0(1-\theta_0)/n}
$$

You have provided $\theta_0=0.075$, $\alpha=0.025$, and $n=100$.

You'll find this formula on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval_or_Wald_interval) as well. It should be noted that a normal approximation is really not ideal for proportions, especially when they approach the parameter boundaries of 0 or 1 (but it's what `rpact` calculates).

*Edit*: you asked what this 'means' in a comment; it means that if you observe this critical value in your experiment you will end up with *P* $<\alpha$, *if* you use the same calculations in your analysis. Recall that the Z-test approximation to a binomial proportion is:

$$
\frac{\hat\theta n - \theta_0 n}{\sqrt{n\ \theta_0(1-\theta_0)}} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
$$

So, using the following `R` code we can calculate normal quantiles and thereby *P*-values for given $\theta_0$, $\hat\theta$, and $n$ - ignoring for a second that you can only observe integer responses because that's what the normal approximation does as well:

```
## Calculate a Z quantile based on observed & assumed proportion
binomZ <- function(p, p0, n) {
   (p*n - p0*n) / sqrt(n*p0*(1-p0))
}

## One-sided P-value if we would observe p=0.126
pnorm(binomZ(.126, .075, 100), lower.tail = FALSE)
> 0.02641657

## One-sided P-value if we would observe p=0.127
pnorm(binomZ(.127, .075, 100), lower.tail = FALSE)
> 0.02417674
```

Notice how 0.127 is where *P* dives under your one-sided $\alpha=0.025$. I want to stress again that you can only actually observe $\hat\theta=0.12$ or $\hat\theta=0.13$ with $n=100$ and that the normal approximation is a pretty bad shortcut for all of this, but at least I hope this clarifies how the calculations happen & how they relate.

As a final note, the confidence interval at the observed $\hat\theta$ mustn't exclude $\theta_0$ because the variance approximation is different, specifically, the lower limit of the normal-approximate CI at the observed critical value will extend down to 0.0614. This doesn't matter because you test *under $H_0$*.

Comment: thank you so much. what does it mean? how to interpret this 'critical value'? someone told me that as long as the point estimation from these 100 subejcts is greater than this critical value, i.e., 0.127, then the lower limit of limit of the confidence interval of the point estimaiton will be greater than H0, i.e., 0.075, but seems it's not correct. can you please help me understand this 'critcal value' ? thank you

Comment: @Stat_Stat I updated my answer to address your additional questions.

Comment: my null hypothesis is H0: theta <0.075, H1:  theta =0.2. my sample size is 100. So my the lower bound of 95% CI being >0.075  is same as a P value of < than 0.025 (one sided), am I right? If the observed theta _hat is 0.127, i.e., critical value, then the 95% CI is 0.127- 1.96*sqrt(0.127*(1-0.127)/100), which is 0.0617 which is lower than H0, NULL is not rejected. so I am confused why it havs to be 'under null hypothesis', i.e., SD is sqrt(0.075*(1-0.075)/100)?

Comment: You test the alternative hypothesis as the probability of observing your data under the nulll hypothesis (one of the unintuitive shortcomings of hypothesis testing - you *assume* $H_0$ is true), and for $\hat\theta\ge 0.127$ this probability goes below $0.025$ (one-sided). This is really quite standard under a frequentist framework which gives you $Pr(X|H_0)$, perhaps Bayesian might be a better philosophical fit? That'll allow you to get $Pr(H_0|X)$.